# Automatically certbot renew wildcard certificates on NameCheap - port 53 problem?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, certbot, namecheap

I'm trying to get an AWS/Lightsail Debian server automatically renewing certificates with certbot. My DNS is with Namecheap.

I'm follow the steps on https://blog.bryanroessler.com/2019-02-09-automatic-certbot-namecheap-acme-dns/ and https://blog.bryanroessler.com/2019-02-09-automatic-certbot-namecheap-acme-dns/. I keep getting a no-permission error.

I run:

> sudo certbot certonly -d "*.example.com" --agree-tos --manual-public-ip-logging-ok --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory --preferred-challenges dns --manual --manual-auth-hook /etc/letsencrypt/acme-dns-auth.py --debug-challenges

I see:

> Failed authorization procedure. example.com (dns-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: No TXT record found at _acme-challenge.example.com

It says I need to open port 53. I followed [Amazon's Lightsail instructions](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/understanding-firewall-and-port-mappings-in-amazon-lightsail). Neither iptables nor ufw seems to be installed. When I nmap my machine, I don't see 53. I actually installed ufw for lack of a good idea, to no avail.

My /etc/acme-dns/config.cfg is as follows:

```
#/etc/acme-dns/config.cfg
[general]
# DNS interface
listen = ":53"
protocol = "udp"
# domain name to serve the requests off of
domain = "acme.example.com"
# zone name server
nsname = "ns1.acme.example.com"
# admin email address, where @ is substituted with .
nsadmin = "example.example.com"
# predefined records served in addition to the TXT
records = [
    "acme.example.com. A <public ip>",
    "ns1.acme.example.com. A <public ip>",
    "acme.example.com. NS ns1.acme.example.com.",
]
debug = false

[database]
engine = "sqlite3"
connection = "/var/lib/acme-dns/acme-dns.db"

[api]
api_domain = ""
ip = "127.0.0.1"
disable_registration = false
autocert_port = "80"
port = "8082"
tls = "none"
corsorigins = [
    "*"
]
use_header = false
header_name = "X-Forwarded-For"

[logconfig]
loglevel = "debug"
logtype = "stdout"
logformat = "text"
```

For the `listen` value, I also tried 127.0.0.1:53 and :53

The settings portion of /etc/letsencrypt/acme-dns-auth.py:

```
# URL to acme-dns instance
ACMEDNS_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8082"
# Path for acme-dns credential storage
STORAGE_PATH = "/etc/letsencrypt/acmedns.json"
# Whitelist for address ranges to allow the updates from
# Example: ALLOW_FROM = ["192.168.10.0/24", "::1/128"]
ALLOW_FROM = []
# Force re-registration. Overwrites the already existing acme-dns accounts.
FORCE_REGISTER = False
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/understanding-firewall-and-port-mappings-in-amazon-lightsail

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish to maintain your own acme DNS server, I built and use this script to automatically renew NameCheap wildcard certs with certbot.  I hope it helps:

https://github.com/scribe777/letsencrypt-namecheap-dns-auth